# Mapstruct: kotlin data class with boolean property

Tags: kotlin, mapstruct, data-class

two simple data classes

```
data class InObj(val isActive: Boolean)
data class OutObj(val isActive: Boolean)

@Mapper
interface Mapper {
    fun inToOut(inObj: InObj): OutObj
}
```

this case will produce the following code, where isActive is not mapped,

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2021-09-29T12:15:55+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.4.2.Final, compiler: IncrementalProcessingEnvironment from kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle-1.5.10.jar, environment: Java 15.0.2 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
public class MapperImpl implements Mapper {

    @Override
    public OutObj inToOut(InObj inObj) {
        if ( inObj == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        boolean isActive = false;

        OutObj outObj = new OutObj( isActive );

        return outObj;
    }
}
```

when "isActive" property is changed to "active" in OutObj class then mapstruct will correctly mapped this property.

```
data class InObj(val isActive: Boolean)
data class OutObj(val active: Boolean)

@Mapper
interface Mapper {
    fun inToOut(inObj: InObj): OutObj
}
...
public class MapperImpl implements Mapper {

    @Override
    public OutObj inToOut(InObj inObj) {
        if ( inObj == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        boolean active = false;

        active = inObj.isActive();

        OutObj outObj = new OutObj( active );

        return outObj;
    }
}
```

so is this a bug in mapstruct or am I missing something?

Comment: Same problem, any solution?

Answer (score 2):

One way to work around the problem caused by kotlin's clever "design" in this area (see e.g. [`KT-63097`](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-63097), to see why this was a mistake in my opinion) is to explicitly declare the JVM method names generated for properties as follows:

```kotlin
data class InObj(
    @get:JvmName("getIsActive")
    val isActive: Boolean
)
data class OutObj(
    @get:JvmName("getIsActive")
    val isActive: Boolean
)
```

If using `var`, then also specify `@set:JvmName("setIsActive")`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, this works as designed.

The target properties are defined in the data constructor and there the property is named `isActive`. The source properties are determined based on the getters and in this case the getter is called `isActive` which means that the property name is `active`.

This can be considered a problem in Kotlin since it doesn't generate `isIsActive` or `getIsActive` for Java.

There is [this](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2281) issue in MapStruct that talks about different problems with Kotlin data classes that can be voted on in order for us to prioritise it.

Comment: It is java-designed but not kotlin-designed, so any solution for kotlin?

Comment: *"this works as designed"*, where "designed" does a lot of work here, considering that problems like this can arise from this design: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-63097

Comment: When I say "this works as designed" I mean from MapStruct perspective. MapStruct uses the Java Bean convention to determine the properties. Your answer does provide a great way to solve the problem though, I wasn't aware about those options in Kotlin